# RDLC Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, medium-trust

Does anyone know of a free (for a non-profit group) RDLC reporting tool that will work under medium trust in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Our [Data Dynamics Reports](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/) product is not free, but we did implement special support for working in the restrictive medium trust environments. I don't know if it is tested on IIS7 yet, but I presume the security policy is the same so it should work in any case. If it does not let us know and we will surely get it working as this is a scenario we explicitly wanted to make sure that we provide a great solution for. For more information see the following links:

- Brief information about when we added the feature from the Product Manager of Data Dynamics: [http://mrdotnet.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/new-release-of-data-dynamics-reports](http://mrdotnet.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/new-release-of-data-dynamics-reports/) Reports
- Instructions on setting up security in ASP.NET including how to configure medium trust: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ddReports/ddrtskSettingPermissions.html
- General Product Information: [http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/)

Also, you can always contact sales@grapecity.us.com for more information about pricing for non-profit groups.

Hope this helps.

Scott Willeke